User name are getting swaped while working with Windows container using GMSA
Application is deployed on Windows container using GMSA.application is using windows authentication.when multiple user use application at Same time,user names are getting swamped
We tried settings at ingress level but nothing worked

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
